# Printing lines of a CSV containing 2 characters in 1 column and a pattern match in another column

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a 4-column CSV file:

```
01, cat, animal, it catches mice
```

- The file contains many characters from various languages in UTF-8.

How can I print only those lines containing exactly 2 characters in column 2 while also matching the pattern "/to " anywhere on that line in column 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk :

```
$ cat /tmp/l
01, cat, animal, it catches mice
02, ok, aaa, e/tomos
03, bad, qux, vb/tomos

$ awk -F"," 'length($2) == 3 && $4 ~ /\057to/' /tmp/l
02, ok, aaa, e/atmos
```

Comment: `$` is not to type, it represent the shell prompt

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
egrep "[^,]+,\s+[^,]{2},|([^,]+,\s+){3}.*/to.*" your_file
```

Try with this file:

```
01, cat, animal, it catches mice
01, ab, animal, it catches/o mice
01, ca, animal, it catches/to mice
01, cat, animal, it catches m/toice
```

and return:

```
01, ab, animal, it catches/o mice
01, ca, animal, it catches/to mice
01, cat, animal, it catches m/toice
```

Comment: The resulting output seems to only print part of the lines. I have `egrep` version 2.6.3.

Comment: Can you post your result? I am using grep 2.9 in Fedora 15

Comment: I found my mistake. Which commas do I need to substitute if my CSV uses an alternate symbol?

Comment: @Village I think all. You'd better show a sample, easy to explain.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^[^,]*,\s*..,[^,]*,.*\/to/!d' file
```